# SQL Help, Splitting Tax by Tenders

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a Point of Sale system where all checks and tender details exist in a single table. I'm trying to write a SQL query in a way that I can see check totals by tenders to reconcile with cash flow and bank statements. Unfortunately the schema is not mine and can't change it.

One problem I ran into is that there are cases where one check has multiple transactions involving various tenders, therefore I need to do implement (business set) rules to allocate taxes evenly. Those rules might change in the future to say, allocate taxes to CC first if any, so I need to built in some flexibility.

The SQL table looks like this:

| CheckID | LineType | TenderName | LineTotal | Tax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ItemSold |  | 5.00 | 0.25 |
| 1 | TenderTotal | Cash | 5.25 |  |
| 2 | ItemSold |  | 10.00 | 0.50 |
| 2 | TenderTotal | Cash | 5.00 |  |
| 2 | TenderTotal | VISA | 5.50 |  |
| 3 | ItemSold |  | 10.00 | 0.25 |
| 3 | ItemSold |  | 10.00 | 0.25 |
| 3 | TenderTotal | AMEX | 10.25 |  |
| 3 | TenderTotal | VISA | 10.25 |  |
| 4 | ItemSold |  | 10.00 | 0.50 |
| 4 | TenderTotal | Cash | 20.00 |  |
| 4 | TenderTotal | Cash | -9.50 |  |

The resulting report needs to have one row per tender, with tax equally distributed among check tenders, and net revenue being the difference between total sale and tax.

| TenderName | TotalSale | NetRevenue | TaxCollected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cash | 20.75 | 19.75 | 1.00 |
| VISA | 15.75 | 15.25 | 0.50 |
| AMEX | 10.25 | 10.00 | 0.25 |

I tried using Select with Exists, also CTE and recursive CTEs, but can't quite figure it out how to do the tax part cleanly.  Any other SQL tricks I could try?

We are using SQL Server 2012 at the moment, but have plans in plan to upgrade to 2016 in the near future.

Comment: You need to explain the logic here; don't just just us the sample data and expected results and expect us to infer the logic. Considering you state that the logic might need to be changed (easily? By parametrisation?) then knowing how that change will impact any solution we provide is vital

Comment: Also, are solutions that would work on 2016 acceptable if they don't on 2012, considering you state that you are upgrading? (This is not me saying that I can see a solution that uses 2016+ syntax, just finding out if that door is open.)

Comment: Logic is: aggregate all checks by tenders, add up all linetotals as amount tendered and name it TotalSale.

Comment: Sorry, go sidetracked with a call.... Logic as I see it: 
1) add up all lineTotals and Tax per check
2) aggregate all checks by tenders, add up all linetotals as amount tendered and name it TotalSale.  Distribute tax to the different tenders evenly, call it TaxCollected (other business rules might enter here, but let's ignore this for now for sanity sake).    NetRevenue will be the difference between TotalSale and TaxCollected, per tender. Does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the logic is right, but it gets you the results you are after:

```sql
WITH Tenders AS(
    SELECT V.CheckID,
           V.LineType,
           V.TenderName,
           V.LineTotal,
           SUM(CASE WHEN V.TenderName IS NULL THEN V.Tax END) OVER (PARTITION BY V.CheckID) AS Tax
    FROM (VALUES(1,'ItemSold',NULL,5.00,0.25),
                (1,'TenderTotal','Cash',5.25,NULL),
                (2,'ItemSold',NULL,10.00,0.50),
                (2,'TenderTotal','Cash',5.00,NULL),
                (2,'TenderTotal','VISA',5.50,NULL),
                (3,'ItemSold',NULL,10.00,0.25),
                (3,'ItemSold',NULL,10.00,0.25),
                (3,'TenderTotal','AMEX',10.25,NULL),
                (3,'TenderTotal','VISA',10.25,NULL),
                (4,'ItemSold',NULL,10.00,0.50),
                (4,'TenderTotal','Cash',20.00,NULL),
                (4,'TenderTotal','Cash',-9.50,NULL))V(CheckID,LineType,TenderName,LineTotal,Tax))
SELECT T.TenderName,
       SUM(T.LineTotal) AS TotalSale,
       SUM(T.LineTotal - T.Tax) AS NetRevenue,
       SUM(T.Tax) AS TaxCollected
FROM Tenders T
WHERE T.TenderName IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY T.TenderName;
```

Comment: Well, I'll be damn. I had to look up Partition but I think that does it. I just transcribed the query to my actual table and I think it works!  I'll need to validate the numbers but for now I just learned something new. Awesome, thanks!